# Using dbCreate option "validate"

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Using Grails 1.3.7 
I am trying to capture SQL changes when I am changing my domain objects. I have set dbCreate = "validate" but I don't get much out of it. I get a missing column exception, and not much else.  Am I doing something wrong? I guess I was expecting to get a sql script to run (similar to what an update option would do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should switch to using database migrations, e.g. http://www.grails.org/plugin/database-migration

Comment: Thanks Burt, I was under impression this was a 2.0 feature.

Comment: We thought that we might need changes in 2.0, but it ended up being independent of the Grails version.